# windows 7 BSOD non paged error now all windows services hung at started

Tags: windows-7, windows, bsod

Noob poster. Running windows 7, recently updated with all critical updates. Had BSOD with a non paged memory error on startup a few days ago. Otherwise, the system runs well, although I have noticed some problems with Chrome browser crashing, which I just attributed to the usual nonsense.

Tried to run windows update today and found the service was not running. Went to Control Panel > Adminsitrative Tools > Services and found Windows Update not running and all the other services hung at "started".

Started windows update. It hangs at "started" too. Tried to run it, says not runnning, try restart... which has no effect, naturally.

Any ideas? Is this a OS problem or a hardware problem? Virus?

Comment: Please [edit] and post the error code / affect file(s). Otherwise the question is unanswerable.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, very likely a virus. There's a few things you might be able to jimmy it with.

1) Microsoft update fix it. Download it off their website. it'll run a diagnostic set, maybe fix you up.

2) open up a search, look for .cmd. Right click on program cmd in pulldown, choose "run as admin". When you have the dos shell open, type
sfc /scannow

3) Download combofix off of bleepingcomputer.com(there are lookalikes out there that ARE viruses, which is why i recommend getting it there). Run as admin

good luck!

Comment: I think your Solution has insufficient information. Since Virus is not only the reason. Possibly OS has Older version Driver files or Settings in regard of updates stops it. Rejecting updates is a critical issue and has to be considered seriously. Remember, "improper solution deteriorates the standards and credibility of the site".

Answer (score -1):

It appears to have been a bad stick of RAM. Memtest86 found a few thousand errors.

I pulled the bad stick, and my system has been stable and all services running without any hang ups.